# How to skip after_save callback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

Does anyone know how to skip after_save and validate both callback and validations in rails 2.3.8?

I tried

```
    my_object = MyClass.new(:attr1 => 'test' )

    my_oject.save(false)
```

Comment: You mean, how to skip `after_save` callback? Because validations are done before save.

Comment: yes callback edited the post

Comment: I know in Rails 4 you can use `create!` to skip the callbacks

Comment: @RichardPeck that's not true. `create!` [calls `save!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L51), which [triggers callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 2 you can use

```
my_object.send(:create_without_callbacks)
my_object.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```